# Electron Autoupdater with Private GitHub Repository?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-updater

I have implemented Electron AutoUpdater with PRIVATE GitHub Repository as provider to publish electron application. Now, i can publish it using GitHub repository but Whenever AutoUpdater tries to download the updates from GitHub repository, Everytime it prompts with response code 404 Not found.. I have tried passing token in setFeedURL method and also set it in GH_TOKEN but seems like that does not work either.

```
autoUpdater.setFeedURL({ provider: 'github'
, owner: 'owner'
, repo: 'repo-name'
, token: 'token'
, private: true });
```

So, Is there any way to get it working with PRIVATE GitHub Repository ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you using electron [auto-updater](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/auto-updater) module? from the API [documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/auto-updater#autoupdatersetfeedurloptions), I can see that they don't support.

On the other hand, if you are using [electron-updater](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-updater) module, make sure that you are following the [recommended release workflow](https://www.electron.build/configuration/publish#recommended-github-releases-workflow), and you should not use setFeedURL check the note [here](https://www.electron.build/auto-update#quick-setup-guide)

**Updated:**

If you are using [electron-updater](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-updater) and you are publishing to a private repository, you will need to make sure that your token will be available within the `app-update.yml` file, that's why many say it's not recommended, if the token is not set in your `app-update.yml` file you will get 404.

For [electron-updater](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-updater) to auto add your token to the `app-update.yml` file the token should be set within the publish section like the following:

```
  "publish": [
    {
      "provider": "github",
      "private": true,
      "owner": "<github_owner>",
      "repo": "<repo_name>",
      "token": "<your github token>"
    }
  ],
```

This will produce a `app-update.yml` file like the following:

```
owner: <github_owner>
repo: <repo_name>
provider: github
private: true
token: <your github token>
updaterCacheDirName: electron-updater-private-updater
```

Check this [small video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6ZT3.jpg)

Here is my code https://github.com/linuxjuggler/electron-auto-update-example check the `electron-builder.json` file.

**Update 2**

Based on the note mentioned in the [Quick Setup Guide](https://www.electron.build/auto-update#quick-setup-guide) section, you should never call **setFeedURL**.

Comment: Yes i am using electron-updater. referring the workflow mentioned setting GH_TOKEN and private option.but seems it is not available for all the users.

Comment: is it hard for you to share the code snippet for the whole update process, not just the setFeedURL one, cause I remember it worked with me when I test it? but to be honest I advise against using it for releasing your code as the final `app-update.yml` file will contain your `GH_TOKEN` in plain text, and since this the same key you are using for pushing the release anyone can then use it to release a new version. at least this is what I was thinking about. unless you are releasing it for a private group of users.

Comment: Also when you release your code, what is the tag format you use? as github rely on the fact that your tag should prefixed with `v` (https://www.electron.build/configuration/publish#githuboptions) which is true by default.

Comment: Yes, tag format are prefixed with v. just checked and confirmed. 
This is how i am checking for updates  `autoUpdater.checkForUpdates(); autoUpdater.on('checking-for-update', () => {   console.log("CHECKING FOR UPDATES !!");  }); ` and at start of script i am setting that setFeedURL

Comment: i read it works only for release-only github account. i set repository to release-only mode too. that did not work out either.

Comment: I'll create a test project today to remember what I did, and get back to you.

Comment: Yeah it worked for me. somehow release-only repository worked. rest of the configuration was correct as yours. btw .. Great thanks.

Comment: Can we manage somehow target branch name on github to publish ? and targeting any specific branch name to download update from. i want to publish separate release for each environment Dev, QA and PROD based upon some branch strategy.  Or any suggestion for this ?

Comment: Am not sure there is a way to do that, as I know the build will be based on the currently active branch, but you might need to read about channels https://www.electron.build/tutorials/release-using-channels.html this way each environment will get its own, but again am not sure if this is a perfect solution.

Comment: Oh Man !! is this github private repo is unstable ? I literally changed nothing but this github auto update is again stopped working. 404 NOT FOUND `Error: Cannot download "https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo-name/releases/assets/assets-number" status 404: Not Found `

Comment: You may have hit the limit, https://www.electron.build/auto-update#private-github-update-repo , that's why github private is not recommended using S3 or something similar might be a better option that you should check.

Answer (score 6):

[Auto-Update](https://www.electron.build/auto-update) - you can see that private github repos works only for very special cases, and they are recommending to have a separate release-only repository to distribute releases so source is locked down, and you can distribute to controlled machines. It is a useful feature since no server is required, but special use case. Also, you can make this work with s3 bucket or some other upgrade servers.

Comment: yeah, Thanks for putting it on front.

Comment: Just to add to this, a public S3 bucket or a release-only repo are the most sane options. The answer marked as correct suggests putting the GitHub token in the repo, which I wouldn't recommend considering anyone with that token can read/write **any** GitHub repo on that account (that token is shipping with the client!). Nuts used to be a popular proxy server, but it hasn't been maintained, and I haven't found a fork that functions anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [AutoUpdater Git Repo](https://github.com/brunnogrillo/autoUpdater) very helpful and my code is working now. Only change I needed to make is in github yml setting, add a `token=<PersonalAccessToken>` from github.

You can get Github personal token from `Github > Settings > Developer Settings > Personal access tokens > Generate New Token`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having this problem (I was stuck for weeks), I created a package to help with this. [electron-github-autoupdater](https://github.com/christianblandford/electron-github-autoupdater/tree/993ec8f8a9e3a32b7324ab9864de92311082d723)

It's pretty much an exact clone of Electron's autoUpdate API that accepts a config object for your private/enterprise github repo configuration and access token. It should *just work*.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).